# Python MQTT, setting timeout for connecting?

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm trying to create a function to check if the server I am connecting to is up or down. I can successfully connect to the server and simulate what would happen when the server is fine, but to simulate what would happen when the server is down, I input the wrong port number like so:

```
client = mqtt.Client()
#I have a defined on_connect function
client.on_connect = on_connect 

#Correct port number
#client.connect(url, 1883)

#Wrong port number
client.connect(url, 2000)

#Check if connection works with a small delay
client.loop_start()
sleep(4)
client.loop_stop()
```

The code runs instantly when the port number is correct.

But when the port number is incorrect (or server is down), it takes approximately 5 minutes. I wanted to speed this up because this code's purpose is to only check whether the server is up or not.

I experimented with keepAlive and set it as low as 0.2, but it doesn't seem to affect it much.

How should I set a timeout so that if it doesn't receive a response in say 4 seconds, it just returns (not connected)?

Answer (score 2):

The keepalive timeout will only come into play once the connection has opened, it is used to measure the time between MQTT control packets.

To do what you need will be a bit trickier. The best approach is probably to use the `on_socket_open()` [callback](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#on-socket-open) and a background thread with a timer started just before the call to `client.connect()`